# Access instance of currently viewed fragment attached using viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have implemented swipe fragments using 
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
or
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/some_background_fragment_container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/pager"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Here is MyActivity.java:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overlay);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return new Page0Fragment();
            else
                return new Page1Fragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to access the currently viewed fragment like this

```
 public void myonclickmethod(View view) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();       
    fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.pager);//<=**This is coming as instance of Page0Fragment inspite of me intializing the activity with Page1Fragment and also currently standing on Page1Fragment without any swiping**
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change your `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` to return the same instance everytime instead of new `Page0Fragment` like:

```
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
            List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
            public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
                fragments.add(new Page0Fragment());
                fragments.add(new Page1Fragment());
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return fragments.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return fragments.size();
            }
```

Now for getting visible fragment, do like:

```
public void myonclickmethod(View view) {
    int currentPosition = mPager.getCurrentItem();
    if(currentPosition == 0 {
        Page0Fragment page0Fragment = (Page0Fragment)mPagerAdapter.getItem(currentPosition);
        page0Fragment.doSomething();
    } else {
        Page1Fragment page1Fragment =(Page1Fragment)mPagerAdapter.getItem(currentPosition);
       pag1Fragment.doSomething();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current fragment by calling getItem() with the current position on your adapter like this

```
    public void myonclickmethod() {
       Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(viewpager.getCurrentItem())
}
```

Comment: This is correct but as the adapter returns the new Fragment() inside getItem() method, calling this method won't give the same fragment instance which is inflated in ViewPager. so calling any method from retrieved fragment will result mostly in NullPointerException. So @OP change your adapter as well.

Comment: @sam_0829 Exactly I had to currect my getItem() implementation to cache instances created earlier to make it fully working.